# Пробрасывание событий наверх

Tags: c#

Есть некий фабричный статик класс (условно он будет на уровне 1)
Эта фабрика создает объекты совершенно другого класса (назовем их уровнем 2)
Объект на уровне 2 в свою очередь создает еще объекты, которые получаются еще ниже - уровень 3. И так далее.

---

Весь апофеоз работы объекта lvl2, созданного на фабрике, находится в одном из методов, который выполняется в объекте на самом последнем уровне. После того, как этот метод отработает, объект lvl2 больше не нужен, и его надо удалить. Но объект по идее не должен удалять сам себя и я не думаю, что потомки тоже имеют право удалять родителя.

Следовательно, задача: из фабрики удалить объект lvl2, учитывая, что фабрика ничего не знает об объектах, которые создает сфабрикованный ею объект, и когда они заканчивают свою работу.

---

Я решил, что если можно пробрасывать исключения, то почему бы не пробросить события? Ну и сделал это.
Объектом на последнем уровне у меня является кнопка. Обычная кнопка, по нажатию на которую должна закрываться форма, и удаляться объект открывший эту форму, и все объекты, которые были созданы на этой форме, вместе с этой кнопкой.
Вот часть кода этой кнопки:

```
public delegate void FormCloseHandler(Object sender, EventArgs arg);
public event FormCloseHandler Event_CloseForm;

// Обработчик нажатия кнопки - метод закрытия формы
private void ButtonCloseOnClick(Object sender, EventArgs arg)
{
   if (Event_CloseForm != null)
      Event_CloseForm(workerParent, new EventArgs());  // workerParent это объект, который создал кнопку. Родитель, можно сказать.
}

protected Button CreateButton(Control parent, ref int controlsTop)
{
...
   button.Click += ButtonCloseOnClick;
...
}
```

это часть кода класса-родителя этой кнопки, который в свою очередь был создан фабрикой:

```
public delegate void FormCloseHandler(UIConstructor_CreateEditForms_Worker worker, EventArgs arg);
public event FormCloseHandler Event_GettingButtonDeleteEvent;

public void On_Event_GettingButtonDeleteEvent(object sender, EventArgs arg)
{
   if (object.ReferenceEquals(this, (UIConstructor_CreateEditForms_Worker)sender))
   {
      form.Close(); // форма, которую обрабатывает этот объект
      components.Clear(); // это все кнопки, лэйблы, текстбоксы и тд, который созданы этим объектом и размещены на форме
      if (Event_GettingButtonDeleteEvent != null)
         Event_GettingButtonDeleteEvent(this, new EventArgs());
   }
}  
...
buttons.Event_CloseForm += On_Event_GettingButtonDeleteEvent; // подписываемся на событие нажатия кнопки
...
```

Ну а это та часть фабричного класса, которая слушает желания о *смерти* созданных им объектов:

```
...
SubscribeOnWorkerDeleteEvent(worker);
...

// подписка на событие удаление рабочего
private static void SubscribeOnWorkerDeleteEvent(UIConstructor_CreateEditForms_Worker worker)
{
   worker.Event_GettingButtonDeleteEvent += DeleteWorker;
}

private static void DeleteWorker(UIConstructor_CreateEditForms_Worker worker, EventArgs arg)
{
   AddOrDeleteWorker(worker); // тут фабрика удаляет объект из своей коллекции
   worker = null;
}
```

И так, что я хочу спросить:

1. приветствуется ли вообще такая практика пробрасывания событий?
2. правильно ли я всё это сделал? Если нет, то как будет правильно?

Comment: @DreamChild, Я ожидал такой реакции. И прошу прощения.  
Просто один товарищ, который даже не модератор, взял да и изменил теги в моих вопросах. Я просто вернул все как было.

Comment: @DreamChild: я бы сказал, это недостаток движка.

Comment: @VladD это да, он тут не без недостатков)

Comment: @VladD, @DreamChild, вот это я понимаю захламление -  
https://pp.vk.me/c614927/v614927120/124d1/13W1f977KDs.jpg  

----  

А у меня так, баловство :)

Comment: @teanЫЧ: Угу, надо бы написать на мету feature request, что закрытие вопроса не должно его поднимать. И приаттачить вас скриншот в качестве пруфов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Несколько мыслей по поводу вашего дизайна.

Во-первых, то, что вы описываете, чересчур абстрактно. Правильную архитектуру невозможно построить в абстрактных терминах: для каждой конкретной предметной области естественным может быть своё решение. (Пример: в программе есть объекты `A`, `B` и `C`, по одной штуке. Кто из них с кем должен взаимодействовать, кто кого контролировать? Непонятно. Но если это не просто `A`, `B` и `C`, а, скажем, `Мотор`, `Автомобиль` и `Человек`, сразу всё становится очевидно.) Поэтому может быть стоит попробовать переформулировать задачу в терминах настоящих, используемых в программе понятий.

Во-вторых, если программа содержит UI, для начала стоит разделить её на модель, представление и что-у-вас-там-посередине (controller или VM). Это, конечно, не абсолютно необходимо, но часто помогает правильно выстроить ответственности. Здесь уже сразу понятно, что за время жизни отвечает controller/VM.

В-третьих, ничего плохого в пробросе event'ов как таковом нет. Но для вашего случая обычной практикой является использование [команд](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.aspx), поставляемых из контроллера, вместо событий view для того, чтобы устранить ненужную зависимость контроллера от view.

В-четвёртых, заданием фабрики традиционно является лишь создание объектов, а не контроль их времени жизни. Объекты, которые хотят разрешить контролировать своё время жизни, обычно просто реализуют `IDisposable`. (Хотя, конечно, это не абсолютное правило, а лишь рекомендация.)

То есть, вполне возможной архитектурой является следующая:

1. Бизнес-логика (ну и термин придумали, а?) находится в контроллере и создаёт модельные объекты через модельную же фабрику.
2. Также бизнес-логика принимает решение о том, что надо показать UI. UI-layer (он же уровень представления) строит нужные визуальные элементы по информации, предоставленной контролером.
3. Нажатие на кнопку в UI активизирует команду, которую для UI поставляет контроллер. Контроллер решает, нужно ли закрывать текущую логическую операцию.
4. Если текущая логическая операция окончена, контроллер информирует об этом UI, и оно убивает свои объекты (в WinForms формы, кажется, имплементируют `IDisposable`, так что «сообщение» может быть просто вызовом `Dispose`). Также контроллер уничтожает модельные объекты, которые больше не нужны.
5. Как именно разрушается объект UI — внутреннее дело уровня представления. Иерархическое разрушение кажется мне хорошей идеей. То же относится к модельным объектам.

Comment: P. S.: жаль, что @Котик больше не появляется, такие вопросы в его духе.